# Is there a way to save nested entities in gcloud-python?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, gcloud-python, google-cloud-python

I'm trying to save an object into Cloud Datastore, the object contains a dictionary as a property value:

```
client = datastore.Client(project_id)
key = client.key('Config', 'config', 'Environment', 'env_name')
env = datastore.entity.Entity(key)
env['prop1'] = dict(foo='bar')
client.put(env)
```

but it raises

> ValueError: Unknown protobuf attr type

Although I'm able to do so using gcloud-node.

Is it possible to save compound object using gcloud-python?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're interested in storing an embedded entity, which I believe is what gcloud-node does automagically.

I think you can do this by setting the field (`prop1`) to a `datastore.Entity` containing a sub-property (`foo`) set to `'bar'`.

```
client = datastore.Client(project_id)
key = client.key('Config', 'config', 'Environment', 'env_name')
env = datastore.Entity(key)
env['prop1'] = datastore.Entity(key=client.key('EmbeddedKind')
env['prop1']['foo'] = 'bar'
client.put(env)
```

When you get this back, it'll look like...

```
>>> c.get(env.key)
<Entity[{'kind': u'Config', 'name': u'config'}, {'kind': u'Env', 'name': u'env_name'}] {u'prop1': <Entity[{'kind': u'Embedded'}] {u'foo': 'bar'}>}>
```

Comment: Thank you for response! When I create a sub-entity with gcloud-node it doesn't create a new kind, why is it the only way in gcloud-python? it would be nice to avoid creating a new kind for embedded entity like gcloud-node does.

Comment: I agree -- any interest in filing an issue against gcloud-python so the folks over there can get to work on it ?